# Remove Symfony2 API URL trailing slash

Tags: symfony

I'm starting to design an API with Symfony2, and I have a problem with the trailing slashes on routes.

For example, let's say I have a Person entity, prefixed with /person in the routing.yml file:

```
api.persons:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/PersonsController.php"
    type: annotation
    prefix: /persons
```

And in the annotations of the controller:

```
@Route("/", methods="{GET}", name="persons_get"))
```

The result of Symfony2 command `router:debug` will give me this URL : `/persons/`. I want to remove this trailing slash. Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this issue too some time ago and while looking for a solution I find this: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1972

I agree with Fabien (fabpot), since prefixes are used in the same way as directories, you are forced to set a string that will be appended to the prefix, and using an empty route is a nonsense.

If you do not want trailing slashes then define it as:

```
@Route("/persons", methods="{GET}", name="persons_get")
```

Use prefixes just for composition purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've read what Fabien said, and I understand it's vision.